# Django CBV Update ValueError Cannot assign None

Tags: django, django-forms, django-class-based-views

After creating the initial data (CreateView) I then proceed to update more data (UpdateView), yet I get the following answer while tring to update the new data. I am attaching the relvelant parts of the code:

```
ValueError at /preinscripcion/padres/63
Cannot assign None: "Alumni.cycle" does not allow null values.
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://decroly.administracionescolarmexico.com/preinscripcion/padres/63
Django Version: 1.5
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value:    
Cannot assign None: "Alumni.cycle" does not allow null values.
Exception Location: /home/fbenavides/webapps/django/lib/python2.7/django/db/models/fields/related.py in __set__, line 401
Python Executable:  /usr/local/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.5
```

Model.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Create your models here
from django.db    import models
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.conf  import settings
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage
import os.path
import datetime

# Create your models here
class ScholarCycle(models.Model):
"""
ScholarCycle
Yearly School Cycle (e.g. 2012-2013)
"""
cycle = models.CharField(blank=False, max_length=9, verbose_name=u'Ciclo Escolar')

def __unicode__(self):
    return u'%s' % self.cycle

class Meta:
    db_table = u'Ciclo Escolar'
    ordering = ['id', 'cycle']
    verbose_name = u'Ciclo Escolar'
    verbose_name_plural = u'Ciclos Escolares'

class Admin:
    pass

fs_photos = FileSystemStorage(location='/media/user/photos')
fs_docs   = FileSystemStorage(location='/media/user/docs')

class Alumni(models.Model):
"""
"""
cycle = models.ForeignKey(ScholarCycle, unique=False, null=False, blank=True, verbose_name=u'Ciclo Escolar')
```

url.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^lista/$', views.AlumniList.as_view(), name='alumni-lista'),
url(r'^lista/(?P<page>\d+)$', views.AlumniRedirectMostrar.as_view(), name='alumni-redirect-mostrar'),
url(r'^mostrar/(?P<pk>\d+)$', views.AlumniRetrieve.as_view(), name='alumni-mostrar'),
url(r'^mostrar/padres/(?P<pk>\d+)$', views.AlumniRetrievePadres.as_view(), name='alumni-mostrar-padres'),
url(r'^mostrar/autorizado/(?P<pk>\d+)$', views.AlumniRetrieveAutorizado.as_view(), name='alumni-mostrar-autorizado'),
url(r'^mostrar/finanzas/(?P<pk>\d+)$', views.AlumniRetrieveFinanzas.as_view(), name='alumni-mostrar-finanzas'),
url(r'^mostrar/documentos/(?P<pk>\d+)$', views.AlumniRetrieveDocumentos.as_view(), name='alumni-mostrar-documentos'),
url(r'^inscripcion/$', views.AlumniRegister.as_view(), name='alumni-inscripcion'),
url(r'^inscripcion/padres/(?P<pk>\d+)$', views.AlumniRegisterPadres.as_view(), name='alumni-inscripcion-padres'),
url(r'^inscripcion/autorizado/(?P<pk>\d+)$', views.AlumniRegisterAutorizado.as_view(),      name='alumni-inscripcion-autorizado'),
url(r'^inscripcion/finanzas/(?P<pk>\d+)$', views.AlumniRegisterFinanzas.as_view(),        name='alumni-inscripcion-finanzas'),
url(r'^inscripcion/documentos/(?P<pk>\d+)$', views.AlumniRegisterDocumentos.as_view(),      name='alumni-inscripcion-documentos'),
url(r'^preinscripcion/$', views.AlumniPreinscripcion.as_view(), name='alumni-preinscripcion'),
url(r'^preinscripcion/padres/(?P<pk>\d+)$', views.AlumniPreinscripcionPadres.as_view(),      name='alumni-preinscripcion-padres'),
url(r'^preinscripcion/autorizados/(?P<pk>\d+)$', views.AlumniPreinscripcionAutorizados.as_view(), name='alumni-preinscripcion-autorizados'),
url(r'^preinscripcion/finanzas/(?P<pk>\d+)$',    views.AlumniPreinscripcionFinanzas.as_view(),    name='alumni-preinscripcion-finanzas'),
```

views.py

```
class AlumniPreinscripcion(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model               = models.Alumni
    form_class          = forms.AlumniFormPreinscripcion
    context_object_name = 'alumno'
    template_name       = 'alumni_preinscripcion.html'
    def get_initial(self):
        initial = super(AlumniPreinscripcion, self).get_initial()
        initial['cycle'] = models.ScholarCycle.objects.get(cycle__exact='2014-2015')
        return initial
    def get_success_url(self, **kwargs):
        return reverse('alumni-preinscripcion-padres', kwargs={'pk':self.object.id})

class AlumniPreinscripcionPadres(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model               = models.Alumni
    form_clas           = forms.AlumniFormPreinscripcionPadres
    context_object_name = 'alumno'
    template_name       = 'alumni_preinscripcion_padres.html'
    def get_sucess_url(self, **kwargs):
        return reverse('alumni-preinscripcion-autorizados', kwargs='pk':self.object.id})
```

alumni_preinscripcion_padres.html

```
{% extends "preinscripcion.html" %}
{% load i18n %}
{% load l10n %}

{% block content %}
  <h2>Padres</h2>
  <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="utf-8">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <fieldset>
      <legend><strong>&nbsp;Pap&aacute;&nbsp;</strong></legend>
      <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span2">
          <p>Nombre:</p>
        </div>
        <div class="span10">
          <p>{{ form.father_name }} {{ form.father_familynames }}</p>
        </div>
      </div>

    <br />
    <p><input type="submit" value="Persona(s) Autorizada(s) &rarr;" /></p>
  </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `cycle` field on your Alumni model is defined with `null=False, blank=True`. You probably want to change that. I can't tell you the *correct* values because that depends on your application logic, but those values are working at odds with your form views. From the [documention](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/fields/#field-options):

> null is purely database-related, whereas blank is validation-related.
>   If a field has blank=True, form validation will allow entry of an
>   empty value. If a field has blank=False, the field will be required.

Read that entire section. Once you understand the proper settings for your Model fields, the forms and class-based-views will most likely work just fine. (FYI, the reason your CreateView works is because you specifically set `initial['cycle']` which satisfies the null criteria whereas you don't do that in UpdateView and the update form thinks it's okay to have blank/empty values.)

**Update:** There are two typos in your `AlumniPreinscripcionPadres` view, `get_sucess_url()` and `form_clas`, both missing a letter.

Comment: Thank you JCotton!!! :) I axamined both Alumni and ScholarCycle and saw what you pointed out. I matched both so null=True and blank=True. Now I do not get the error, but I can not save and I get returned back to the same update page. Logs do not show any errors of any kind.

Comment: @francisco did you see my updated answer? Have you solved this problem?